# How to avoid mutations when using the sub() method in regex?

Tags: python, regex

```
namesRegex = re.compile(r"Agent \w+") 
namesRegex.sub('CENSORED', 'Agent Alice gave the secret documents to Agent Bob.')
```

When I do this, it doesnt only change Agent, but Alice and Bob also. I mean it changes one more word.
I tried to understand this, for example,  when i want to change only Alice, it also changes "gave" too.
How can I only change one word in Regex?

Also one question more, we write like this re.compile(r".* etc")
but even if we dont write "r", like r.compile(".* etc") it does the same thing. Then why do we write r letter over there?

Comment: Thank you, it worked! But is it really the good way to do it? I mean if I want to change a something in the middle of sentence, then i need to write all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make `'Agent '` part of a positive lookbehind pattern instead so that `re.sub` only matches the agent's name and therefore substitutes only the agent's name with `'CENSORED'`:

```
namesRegex = re.compile(r"(?<=Agent )\w+")
```

Comment: This is so wise, it solved... I read all the book(which im reading) about RegEx. But I couldnt get the ?<=Agent part.  Could you please explain a bit, if it doesnt take your time much. I'll be so grateful.

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax), `(?<=...)` matches if the current position in the string is preceded by a match for `...` that ends at the current position. In other words, with `(?<=Agent )\w+`, `\w+` would only match if it is preceded by `Agent `, even though `Agent ` itself would not be part of the match.

Answer (score -1):

Check out [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/npHuK4/1)

You can test regex expressions against different inputs and see what matches. It even explains what rules were used in the match.

For instance, for `Agent \w+` the explanation is:

```
Agent matches the characters Agent literally (case sensitive)
\w+
matches any word character (equal to [a-zA-Z0-9_])
+ Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed
```

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: Thank you @Michael, its nice site you sent the link

Comment: @Nick The question in my understanding is "Why is my regex changing one extra word than I expect it to?". The explanation I put (from regex101) covers that question. The link, gives a tool for further explanation/experimentation.